# Getting aggregated data in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a StatementsEntries table as follows

```
ID  |   Name       |  CaseId | StatementID  | Amount  |  Balance   | Paid
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  |  Statement 1 |    1     |      1       |   1000  |  1000      |   1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2  |  Payment     |    1     |      0       |   1000  |    0       |   0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3  |  Statement 2 |    3     |      2       |    500  |    500     |   0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 4  |  Statement 3 |    4     |      3       |    50   |    50      |   0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 5  |  Payment     |    3     |      0       |    25   |    475     |   0
```

This is an existing table with hundreds of records and basically when there is a Name Statement * and a StatementId it means it was processed "invoiced", then any payments to the same case Id always goes to the older invoice. In this case Statement 1 is fully paid because the statement was generated and then a payment was received for the balance amount.

In the case of Statement 2, it was generated and it received a payment after statement 3 was generated, the payment was for 25 dollars so the payment was applied to Statement 2 with the same caseId, only payments to the specific case id are assigned, so if I had made a payment for CaseId 4, i would have applied it to Statement 3.

I would like to obtain a query with the following results:

```
 StatementId  |  Name        | Amount | Balance | IsPaid
----------------------------------------------------------
      1       |  Statement 1 |  1000  | 1000    |   1
---------------------------------------------------------
      1       |  Statement 1 |  1000  |   0     |   0
----------------------------------------------------------
      2       |  Statement 2 |  500   |  500    |   0
----------------------------------------------------------
      2       |  Statement 2 |   25   |  475    |   0
----------------------------------------------------------
      3       |  Statement 3 |   50   |  50     |   0
```

I have tried using UNION ALL, and joining to the same table but I am struggling setting the StatementId for the record that has the payment. Will appreciate some direction for this.

**UPDATE**
I tried the following script

```
SELECT
    [Statement ID] = CASE WHEN s.StatementId> 0 THEN s.StatementId ELSE x.StatementId END,
    Name = CASE WHEN s.StatementId> 0 THEN s.Description ELSE x.Description END,
    s.Amount,
    s.Balance,
    s.IsPaid
FROM StatementEntries s
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT *
    FROM StatementEntries
    WHERE
        CaseId = s.CaseId
        AND StatementId > s.StatementId AND StatementId > 0
    ORDER BY ID
)x
WHERE s.CaseId = 1
ORDER BY s.ID
```

That yields

```
 StatementId  |  Name        | Amount | Balance | IsPaid
----------------------------------------------------------
      1       |  Statement 1 |  1000  | 1000    |   1
---------------------------------------------------------
      1       |  Statement 1 |  1000  |   0     |   0
----------------------------------------------------------
      2       |  Statement 2 |  500   |  500    |   0
----------------------------------------------------------
      1       |  Statement 1 |   25   |  475    |   0
----------------------------------------------------------
      3       |  Statement 3 |   50   |  50     |   0
```

See record #4, it should show Statement ID 2 and Statement 2. I am working on it trying to make it work, thank you so much for the answer though i think it's setting me in the right path.

**UPDATE 2 (Adding schema and sample data)**

```
CREATE TABLE StatementsEntries (
    Id              INT,
    Name            VARCHAR(200),
    Date            DATE,
    IsCredit        BIT,
    Amount          DECIMAL,
    CaseId          INT,
    IsAdjustment    BIT,
    StatementId     INT,
    Balance         DECIMAL,
    IsPaid          BIT,
    CreateDate      DATE
)

INSERT INTO StatementsEntries  VALUES
(1, 'Statement 4444','04/01/2007',0, 850,1,0,4444,850,1,'04/01/2007'),
(2, 'Payment made', '04/02/2007', 1, 850,1,0,0,0,0,'04/02/2007'),
(3, 'Statement 5555','08/01/2008', 0,1003, 1,0,5555,1003, 0,'08/01/2008'),
(4, 'Statement 7777','09/01/2008',0, 3000,2,0,7777,3000,0,'09/01/2008'),
(5, 'Statement 8883','10/01/2008', 0,1500, 5,0,8883,1500, 1,'10/01/2008'),
(6, 'Payment made', '10/02/2008', 1, 1500,5,0,0,0,0,'10/02/2008'),
(7, 'Statement 9992','11/01/2008',0, 1750,7,0,9992,1750,0,'11/01/2008'),
(8, 'Payment made', '04/02/2009', 1, 1002,1,0,0,648,0,'04/02/2009'),
(9, 'Statement 9994','08/01/2010', 0,1650, 1,0,9994,1650, 1,'08/01/2010'),
(10, 'Payment made', '09/02/2011', 1, 10,1,0,0,638,0,'09/02/2011');
```

Comment: Show us your current query, sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample Data:

```
Id          Name            Date       IsCredit Amount      CaseId      IsAdjustment StatementId Balance     IsPaid CreateDate
----------- --------------- ---------- -------- ----------- ----------- ------------ ----------- ----------- ------ ----------
1           Statement 4444  2007-04-01 0        850         1           0            4444        850         1      2007-04-01
2           Payment made    2007-04-02 1        850         1           0            0           0           0      2007-04-02
3           Statement 5555  2008-08-01 0        1003        1           0            5555        1003        0      2008-08-01
4           Statement 7777  2008-09-01 0        3000        2           0            7777        3000        0      2008-09-01
5           Statement 8883  2008-10-01 0        1500        5           0            8883        1500        1      2008-10-01
6           Payment made    2008-10-02 1        1500        5           0            0           0           0      2008-10-02
7           Statement 9992  2008-11-01 0        1750        7           0            9992        1750        0      2008-11-01
8           Payment made    2009-04-02 1        1002        1           0            0           648         0      2009-04-02
9           Statement 9994  2010-08-01 0        1650        1           0            9994        1650        1      2010-08-01
10          Payment made    2011-09-02 1        10          1           0            0           638         0      2011-09-02
```

**SOLUTION**

```
SELECT
    s.id,
    [Statement ID] = CASE WHEN s.StatementID > 0 THEN s.StatementID ELSE x.StatementID END,
    Name = CASE WHEN s.StatementID > 0 THEN s.Name ELSE x.Name END,
    s.Amount,
    s.Balance,
    s.IsPaid
FROM StatementsEntries s
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM StatementsEntries
    WHERE
        CaseID = s.CaseID
        AND StatementID > 0
        AND ID < s.Id
    ORDER BY ID Desc
)x
ORDER BY [Statement ID], s.Id
```

**RESULT**

```
id          Statement ID Name            Amount      Balance     IsPaid
----------- ------------ --------------- ----------- ----------- ------
1           4444         Statement 4444  850         850         1
2           4444         Statement 4444  850         0           0
3           5555         Statement 5555  1003        1003        0
8           5555         Statement 5555  1002        648         0
4           7777         Statement 7777  3000        3000        0
5           8883         Statement 8883  1500        1500        1
6           8883         Statement 8883  1500        0           0
7           9992         Statement 9992  1750        1750        0
9           9994         Statement 9994  1650        1650        1
10          9994         Statement 9994  10          638         0
```

Comment: This is the closest one  thank you so much, the only problem i have and i have to modify it a bit is that for multiple items with same CaseId, it always takes the maximum StatementId so i tried modifying it but now it gives me another issue where it's picking the first statement id for all the ones that have 0. See edited question.

Comment: Hello @wewesthemenace, I updated the data more to what we have on production in SQL Fiddle Demo, as you can see it is not grouping them correctly for example StatementId 4444 was for 850 and the payment was for 850 but the payment is showing all the way at the bottom and with the wrong StatementId, the original data is in the insert statements. This is driving me nuts :( . Thank you for all the help!  I pasted the schema used here.. i did not know i could not modify the original Fiddle

Comment: No problem. Anyway, this is my first time answering a bounty question. Did I receive the bounty when you marked it as answer?

Comment: dunno, i hope you did! :)

Comment: It says i have to award it in 23 hours

Comment: I will make sure you get it!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Cross Apply`

```
SELECT Dense_rank()OVER(ORDER BY cs.name) StatementID,
       cs.name,
       amount,
       Balance,
       paid
FROM   Yourtable a
       CROSS apply (SELECT TOP 1 name
                    FROM   Yourtable  b
                    WHERE  a.CaseId = b.CaseId
                    ORDER  BY id) cs
```

[**SqlFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2ade/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select distinct src.caseid, 
src.name, 
max(src.statementid) over (partition by src.caseid order by src.id)   statementid, 
src.amount, 
src.balance, 
src.paid ispaid
from tbl src
left join tbl tgt on tgt.caseid = src.caseid and tgt.statementid = 0
order by caseid, src.balance desc
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/YOORB54820)

Note: This will not work with SQL Server version below SQL Server 2005.

Comment: I tried this one but it tells me that there is a syntax error in "order", and its on the line where the partition is. Thanks a lot!, this is a pretty cool script

Comment: Hmm, I don't see the error in my demo, but perhaps your column names are slightly different? I'd be happy to help if you could set up a SQL Fiddle or something to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @ergwin, What's your version of SQL Server?

Comment: I added sample data from a production database, if you paste the last schema and records i added you can see the issue. Thanks a lot i appreciate all the help i am receiving from you guys

Answer (score 0):

Using the sample data, the following query:

```
SELECT S.Id, S.Name, S.Date, S.IsCredit, S.Amount, S.CaseId, S.IsAdjustment, S.StatementId, S.Balance, S.IsPaid, S.CreateDate
FROM 
    StatementsEntries S
WHERE
   S.IsCredit = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT P.Id, S.Name, P.Date, P.IsCredit, P.Amount, P.CaseId, P.IsAdjustment, S.StatementId, P.Balance, P.IsPaid, P.CreateDate
FROM 
    StatementsEntries P
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP (1)  S.StatementId, S.Name
        FROM StatementsEntries S
        WHERE
            S.CaseId = P.CaseId
            AND S.IsCredit = 0
            AND S.Id < P.Id
        ORDER 
            BY S.Id DESC
    ) S
WHERE
    IsCredit = 1

ORDER BY StatementId, Id
```

Produces the following result:

```
╔════╦════════════════╦════════════╦══════════╦════════╦════════╦══════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦════════╦════════════╗
║ Id ║      Name      ║    Date    ║ IsCredit ║ Amount ║ CaseId ║ IsAdjustment ║ StatementId ║ Balance ║ IsPaid ║ CreateDate ║
╠════╬════════════════╬════════════╬══════════╬════════╬════════╬══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬════════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║ Statement 4444 ║ 2007-04-01 ║        0 ║    850 ║      1 ║            0 ║        4444 ║     850 ║      1 ║ 2007-04-01 ║
║  2 ║ Statement 4444 ║ 2007-04-02 ║        1 ║    850 ║      1 ║            0 ║        4444 ║       0 ║      0 ║ 2007-04-02 ║
║  3 ║ Statement 5555 ║ 2008-08-01 ║        0 ║   1003 ║      1 ║            0 ║        5555 ║    1003 ║      0 ║ 2008-08-01 ║
║  8 ║ Statement 5555 ║ 2009-04-02 ║        1 ║   1002 ║      1 ║            0 ║        5555 ║     648 ║      0 ║ 2009-04-02 ║
║  4 ║ Statement 7777 ║ 2008-09-01 ║        0 ║   3000 ║      2 ║            0 ║        7777 ║    3000 ║      0 ║ 2008-09-01 ║
║  5 ║ Statement 8883 ║ 2008-10-01 ║        0 ║   1500 ║      5 ║            0 ║        8883 ║    1500 ║      1 ║ 2008-10-01 ║
║  6 ║ Statement 8883 ║ 2008-10-02 ║        1 ║   1500 ║      5 ║            0 ║        8883 ║       0 ║      0 ║ 2008-10-02 ║
║  7 ║ Statement 9992 ║ 2008-11-01 ║        0 ║   1750 ║      7 ║            0 ║        9992 ║    1750 ║      0 ║ 2008-11-01 ║
║  9 ║ Statement 9994 ║ 2010-08-01 ║        0 ║   1650 ║      1 ║            0 ║        9994 ║    1650 ║      1 ║ 2010-08-01 ║
║ 10 ║ Statement 9994 ║ 2011-09-02 ║        1 ║     10 ║      1 ║            0 ║        9994 ║     638 ║      0 ║ 2011-09-02 ║
╚════╩════════════════╩════════════╩══════════╩════════╩════════╩══════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
SELECT id,
      ISNULL([Statement].StatementId, SE.StatementId) AS StatementId
    , ISNULL([Statement].Name, SE.Name) AS Name
    , Date         
    , IsCredit     
    , Amount       
    , CaseId       
    , IsAdjustment 
    , Balance      
    , IsPaid       
    , CreateDate   
FROM StatementsEntries AS SE
    OUTER APPLY(
        SELECT Name, StatementId
        FROM StatementsEntries AS SE_name
        WHERE SE_name.Id = SE.CaseId
            AND SE.IsCredit = 1
    ) AS [Statement]
ORDER BY StatementId
```